# Karate/Cucumber novice:The baseUrl in karate-config is not recognized

Tags: testng, karate

I am trying Karate with my existing Testng+Restassured setup.
I am new to both Karate and Cucumber.

I am trying to login to my service using a default user and password.
There are multiple challenges for me here, since I don't understand how the control flows currently.

I have the following karate-config.js file:

```
function() {
 karate.configure('connectTimeout', 5000);
 karate.configure('readTimeout', 5000);

 var protocol = 'https';
 var config = { baseUrl: protocol + '://staging.com'};
 return config;
}
```

This is my login.feature file:

```
Feature: login

Background:
  * url baseUrl
  # required payload = {"enc_login_id":"","password":"","timestamp":"","type":"","client":"","encrypted":false,"source":"web"}

    Scenario: Login as User
      # epoch time
      * def time = (new Date).getTime(); 
      Given path '/sso/authenticate'
      And form field enc_login_id = 'demo@gmail.com'
      And form field password = 'gmail1213'
      And form field timeStamp = time
      When method post
      Then status 200
      And def sessionID = response.session_id
      And print 'SessionID: ' , sessionID
```

This is my Login.java file for the feature:

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

@CucumberOptions(
   features = "login.feature"
)
public class LoginKarateTest {

}
```

I get the following error when I run this feature:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: javascript evaluation failed: baseUrl

I don't know if the config is being read here. Is there any setup that I have missed?
Also my request payload has 3 variables and 3 constant attributes. How can I define them? I have commented the payload for reference.

Comment: I just changed by feature file to this and it worked. But I would like to define variables and use them. `Feature:login
Background:
  * url 'https://staging.com
    Scenario: Login as User
      # epoch time
      * def time = (new Date).getTime(); 
      Given path '/sso/authenticate'
      * request = {"enc_login_id":"demo@gmail.com","password":"gmail1213","timestamp":time,"type":"user","client":"gmail","encrypted":false,"source":"web"}
      When method post
      Then status 200
      And def sessionID = response.session_id
      And print 'SessionID: ' , sessionID` but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure your `karate-config.js` is not on the classpath.

Since you are new to all this, I ask you to please please please start a fresh project and not mix TestNG and REST-assured.

Just use the archetype and you will be all up and running: https://github.com/intuit/karate#quickstart

Comment: Hi Peter! I'm also facing the same issue.

`function {

    var config = {
        baseUrl : 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1'
    }

    return config;
}`


`Feature: Create Teams

  Background:
    * url baseUrl
    * def contextPath = '/admin/teams/create'

  Scenario: Verify that a new Team is successfully getting created

    Given path contextPath
    When request {"name":"Test-team","description":"Test","createdBy":"system"}
    And method post
    And header Accept = 'application/json'
    Then status 200
    And print 'Response is: ', response `

Comment: @AkhilSuseelan I'm not reading this at all. follow this process if you can: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 1):

In the above case the issue with java version only as Karate is not supporting on version 1.8.0_101.So just update the java version and it will start working.

Check the java version using java -version
it version is the above once do install java again with command : 
**brew cask install java**
At the end java home path should get change with update java version
**echo $JAVA_HOME**

Change java home export path on base profile and then just reload the base profile.

to open base_profile 
Just do **vi ~/.bash_profile** and go to java home export and then change java version
Then do **source ~/.bash_profile**

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using an IDE like eclipse.In that case first create a karate-config.js file..in any folder ..go to the Project in eclipse in Package explorer window . 
Right click on the project and go to build path.add the folder in your project where the karate-config.js is in the build path.
(This adds the karate-config.js file to the classpath from where java compiler can identify this JS file and compile it)

Like @ Ashok Kumar mentioned after upgrading your java ..try this